# Node JS Sharp - Maintain SVG Font When Converting To JPG

Tags: node.js, svg, image-manipulation, sharp

I am using the sharp library to create dynamic JPEG license plate images.

Basically, I have a PNG that is a vanity license plate with no numbers. Then I create an svg in code like so

```
    const svg = new Buffer(
        `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="${width}" height="${height}" viewBox="${x} ${y} 500 40">
            <defs>
            <style type="text/css">
                <![CDATA[
                    @font-face {
                        font-family: LicensePlate;
                        src: url('LicensePlate.ttf');
                    }
                    svg {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                    }
                ]]>
            </style>
            </defs>

            <text x="0" y="0" font-family="LicensePlate" font-size="${fontsize}" letter-spacing="${letterspace}">
                ${platenumber.toUpperCase()}
            </text>
        </svg>`
    );
```

Passing in the desired width, height, and license plate number. Then I use the sharp library to overlay my SVG in the middle of the license plate. This all works just fine.

However, I have imported a custom license plate font (LicensePlate.ttf). In order to debug my in-code SVG image I made an actual svg image file that I open in the browser to make sure that it all looks correct, which it does.

The problem is that when the final JPEG file is created it does not contain my custom font. Instead it falls back on Verdana.

My question is, is there any way I can maintain the SVG font while creating the image with sharp?

Thanks!

#### Full Code

```
function createImage(platenumber) {
    //Trying to create some sort of responsiveness
    let fontsize = 80;
    let letterspace = 10;
    let width = 300;
    let height = 90;
    let x = 0;
    let y = -45;

    const inputlength = platenumber.length;

    //Minumum Length
    if (inputlength == 2) {
        x = -200;
    }
    if (inputlength == 3) {
        x = -150;
    }
    if (inputlength == 4) {
        x = -130;
    }
    if (inputlength == 5) {
        x = -105;
    }
    if (inputlength == 6) {
        x = -65;
    }


    try {
        console.log('stream is duplex, ', pipe instanceof stream.Duplex);
        //Read the svg code into a buffer with a passed in plate number
        const svg = new Buffer(
            `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="${width}" height="${height}" viewBox="${x} ${y} 500 40">
                <defs>
                <style type="text/css">
                    <![CDATA[
                        @font-face {
                            font-family: LicensePlate;
                            src: url('LicensePlate.ttf');
                        }
                        svg {
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100%;
                        }
                    ]]>
                </style>
                </defs>

                <text x="0" y="0" font-family="LicensePlate" font-size="${fontsize}" letter-spacing="${letterspace}">
                    ${platenumber.toUpperCase()}
                </text>
            </svg>`
        );

        const plateid = rand.generate(10);

        //Create a write stream to a randomly generated file name
        const write = new fs.createWriteStream(`plates/${plateid}.jpg`);

        //Create the sharp pipeline
        const pipeline = pipe
            .overlayWith(svg, { gravity: sharp.gravity.center })//we center the svg image over the top of whatever image gets passed into the pipeline
            .jpeg();//we convert to JPG because it is a compressed file format and will save space (we could also do webp if we really want to be slick about it)

        //Create the read stream from the license plate template
        const read = new fs.createReadStream('plate-2.png')
            .pipe(pipeline)//pipe out sharp pipeline
            .pipe(write);//add the write stream so that our sharp pipeline knows where to put the image

        return plateid;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### SVG Image

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="90" viewBox="0 -50 500 40">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      <![CDATA[
        @font-face {
          font-family: LicensePlate;
          src: url('LicensePlate.ttf');
        }
      ]]>
    </style>
  </defs>

  <text x="0" y="0" font-family="LicensePlate" font-size="150" letter-spacing="10">
    Pl@T3#
  </text>
</svg>
```

#### Exact Font

Here is a link to the exact font I used
http://www.fontspace.com/dave-hansen/license-plate

Comment: did you have any luck solving this issue?

Comment: @gregb unfortunately, no

Comment: The provided answer didn't work? I mean it might be a little late..

Answer (score 3):

I dealt with this problem by installing the font in my OS, when the file is being converted, the libraries can only access OS fonts.

Comment: OH YEAH! That was super helpful! As a side note, I had to provide the full font name as in macOS font collection, whereas in the browser (Chrome) I could just write the first word of my font..

Answer (score 0):

install font on OS, if you using Windows, don't forget install font(s) with All Users for IIS and NodeJS have permission to access the font(s)